# How to take an array of chars and return true if the same character appears more than once

Tags: java

For example: containsTwo( ['a', 'b', 'c'] )  --> false.
containsTwo( ['c', 'a', 'c'] )  --> true

```
public static boolean containsTwo(char[] arr) {
  int pos = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int i2 = 1; i2 < arr.length -1;i2++) {
    if (arr[pos] == arr[i]) {
    return true;
    }
    pos++;
  } return false;
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how I would traverse through the array to check if arr[0] is the same as arr[2] or arr[3]

Comment: For a better performing solution, use a `HashSet<Character>`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using double for loops, consider using Set.

```
public static boolean containsTwo(char[] arr) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (char a : arr) {
        if (set.add(a) == false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You look from left to right. If any character to the right of the present position matches the present position return `true`. If you examine all of the characters `return false`. Like,

```
public static boolean containsTwo(char[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                return true;
            }
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing each element with all other elements of char[] will become more complex in case of huge number of elements.
If your reuirement is only to return True or False depending upon any duplicate character exist in char[], then kindly try to add char[] elements to Set because Set will accept only unique values so; when you are adding element which is already present in Set then it will return False and your requirement fulfills.
Kindly use below complete code.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ArrayToSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayToSet arraySet = new ArrayToSet();
        char[] chars = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
        System.out.println(arraySet.containsTwo(chars));
    }

    public static boolean containsTwo(char[] arr) {
        Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (char ch : arr) {
            if (charSet.add(ch) == false) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```